# Method time calculate

Tags: java, android, collections

I'm having a problem with calculating method time.

```
long startTime = System.nanoTime();
Collections.sort(listOfPictures, new PictureComparator());

long timeAfterSorting = System.nanoTime();

long timeElapsed = TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS.toMillis(timeAfterSorting - startTime);

Toast.makeText(this, getString(
    R.string.info_sort_time) + 
    String.valueOf(timeElapsed) + 
    R.string.info_milliseconds, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

`timeElapsed` returns 0 on the debugger, but on Toast, it shows some random huge numbers.

Using `currentMilisecs()` has the same problem.

I have the same method for shuffling collection, and it returns normal value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> it shows some random huge numbers

That is not surprising. `R.string.info_milliseconds` is a random huge number. Perhaps you really want `getString(R.string.info_milliseconds)`.